# Bond and Stock Relationship

Tags: equities, fixed-income, pricing-formulae

Is there any formulair relationship between the price of a corporate bond and the stock on the same company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structural credit models like the Merton Model attempt to establish the relationship.  However, because the company assets are not trade-able, the delta hedging / no arbitrage assumptions associated with pricing equity options do not hold in this case. [This](https://www.mathworks.com/help/risk/default-probability-using-the-merton-model-for-structural-credit-risk.html) article provides some additional information.